# ¿Como creo una contraseña con condiciones en el ingreso ? Arrays Java

Tags: java

Tengo que crear un programa donde se ingrese una contraseña con una longitud de al menos 8 caracteres y por lo menos un caracter numerico. Si cumple las condiciones debe devolver un `true` en caso contrario un `false`.

Yo hice lo siguiente :

```
public class Contraseña {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Ingrese contraseña : "); 
    char password[] = { teclado.next().charAt(0) }; 
    int i = 0;
    boolean verificacion1 = false;
    boolean verificacion2 = false;
    boolean estado = false;

    for (i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {

        if (password[i] >=0 && password[i]<=7) {  
            if (password[i] < '0' || password[i] > '9') {

                verificacion1 = true;

            }

        }
            if(password[i] >=8) { 

            if (password[i] < 'a' || password[i] > 'z') {

                verificacion2 = true;
            }


    if (verificacion1 == true && verificacion2 == true) {

        estado = true;

    } else {

        estado = false;
    }
        }

    }




System.out.println(estado);
}

}
```

El problema es que cuando ingreso una contraseña (como por ejemplo esta: holamund0 ), respetando las condiciones me da falso, que podria estar mal?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, puede ser porque la variable "password" la estás declarando como un char, por lo que solo almacena el primer caracter de la cadena que estás ingresando, podrías probar haciendo algunos cambios y declarar la variable como un String.

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy clara la lógica que estás usando para hacer la validación, pero seguro que acá tenés un problema:

```
password[i] >=0
```

`password` es un `array` de `char`, y `password[i]` contiene un caracter de tu password.
Estás comparando un caracter con un entero, no con otro caracter.
Esto es válido porque un char puede ser casteado a un int, pero que sea válido no significa que tenga sentido en la forma que lo estás aplicando.

Me parece que lo que en realidad querés hacer o es `i >=0` o `password[i] >= '0'`

En el primer caso estás checkeando la posición del caracter dentro de la `password` (el `array`), y en la segunda estás checkeando el valor del caracter en la posición `i` contra el valor del caracter `'0'`.

Para que se vea la diferencia, el caracter '0' tiene un valor de 48 (en decimal).
[Tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)